# Pandas Duplicated returns some not duplicate values?

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from dataset.

Before using `df.drop_duplicates()`, I run `df[df.duplicated()]` to check which values are treated as duplicates. Values that I don't consider to be duplicates are returned, see example below. All columns are checked.

How to get accurate duplicate results and drop real duplicates?

`city     price      year    manufacturer    cylinders   fuel    odometer
whistler 26880      2016.0  chrysler        NaN         gas     49000.0
whistler 17990      2010.0  toyota          NaN        hybrid   117000.0
whistler 15890      2010.0  audi            NaN         gas     188000.0
whistler 8800       2007.0  nissan          NaN         gas     163000.0`

Comment: you can use `subset` option within `df.drop_duplicates()`. In there you can specify in which columns should be considered for looking for duplicates. I am sure there are other questions showing how it is done.

Comment: city and cilinders are duplicated values, aren't they?

Comment: Yeah, some categorical data is the same including city, manufacturer, cilnders, fuel etc. but most important ones price, year, odometer differ, still it assumes it duplicates.

Comment: You need to add a more complete working example of the problem. When I run `df[df.duplicated()]` on the data you pasted, I get an empty dataframe as expected.

Comment: @ValdemarT - Did you resolve this issue? Any luck? Even am encountering the same issue with `drop_duplicates()`? your inuts would really be helpful

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Where some columns are duplicates but rest of the continuous datatype column are not duplicates. But still the whole row is considered as duplicates

Comment: Encountering the same problem too. 
df.drop_duplicates(subset='my_column_of_interest') returns results which have unique values in my_column_of_interest field.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem.

At first, it looks like

```
df.duplicated(subset='my_column_of_interest')
```

returns results which actually have unique values in *my_column_of_interest* field.

This is not the case, though. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) shows that *duplicated* uses the *keep* parameter to opt for keeping all duplicates, just the first or just the last. Its default value is *first*.

Which means that if you have a value present twice in this column, running
df.duplicated(subset='my_column_of_interest') will return results that only contain this value once (since only its first occurrence is kept).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and couldn't find a clear solution online, so here's what worked for me. After reading what @Mihaela mentioned about the default value for .duplicated(), I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. What I wanted (and I assume you wanted) was to return *all* duplicate rows so you could manually verify that they were, in fact, duplicates. By default, **.duplicated()** will only return *one row* for each set of duplicates. If you want to return *all rows* with duplicate values, you must set **keep=False**.

#### Returns *only one row* for each set of duplicate rows:

```
df[df.duplicated()]
```

Example Output:

| ID | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |

#### Returns *ALL* duplicated rows:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Example Output:

| ID | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |

#### Additional Tip

If your dataframe is not already sorted, your results will return mixed in such a way that it can be hard to see that the rows are really duplicates (which happened to me). Chaining **sort_values()** to the end of the code made it so I could view the sets of duplicate rows together, making it much easier to manually verify that they were identical. Just set the **by=['col']** param to be whichever column(s) make sense for your use-case.

Example Output (unsorted):

| ID | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 1 | 3/2 | 37 |
| 2 | 3/2 | 40 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |
| 2 | 3/2 | 40 |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 1 | 3/2 | 37 |

Code:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(by=['id', 'date'])
```

Example Output (sorted):

| ID | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 1 | 3/1 | 35 |
| 1 | 3/2 | 37 |
| 1 | 3/2 | 37 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 2 | 3/1 | 27 |
| 2 | 3/2 | 40 |
| 2 | 3/2 | 40 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |
| 3 | 3/1 | 89 |